# Django Foreignkey problem,

Tags: django

```
class Service(models.Model)
name = models.CharField("service name", max_length = 20, unique = True)


class Newclass(models.Model):
 service = models.ForeignKey(Services)
 user1 = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Basically what I want is :
For each service I can have different user1, but no duplicate user1 for any service.
example

```
service = 'some'  user1 = 'amit'
service = 'some'   user1 = 'laspal'
service = 'some1'  user1 = 'amit'
```

So how to avoid this conditions:

```
   service = 'some'    user1 = 'amit'
   service = 'some'    user1  = 'amit'
```

Should I check while adding the user1 to newclass or is there some field I am missing out which I can user with Fk().

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you don't want that 2 `Newclass` models can exist with the same service and user1, you should use:

```
class Newclass(models.Model):
  service = models.ForeignKey(Services)
  user1 = models.ForeignKey(User)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = (('service', 'user1'),)
```

Comment: +1 - just noticed the syntax of my `unique_together` clause was wrong, where yours is right (it's a tuple of tuples, not just a tuple).

Comment: Not true, that's also correct and for this case maybe even better: @http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/ `For convenience, unique_together can be a single list when dealing with a single set of fields`

Answer (score 2):

You want [`unique_together`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class Newclass(models.Model):
  service = models.ForeignKey(Services)
  user1 = models.ForeignKey(User)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('service', 'user1')
```

What `unique_together` does (from [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)):

> This is a list of lists of fields that must be unique when considered together. It's used in the Django admin and is enforced at the database level (i.e., the appropriate `UNIQUE` statements are included in the `CREATE TABLE` statement).